# How to use The Movie DB API to show data in PHP

Tags: php, api

This is all what I understood till now:

If i open this URL:

```
https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/tt0137523?api_key=522cec782xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

I will get the following data on screen:

```
{"adult":false,"backdrop_path":"/87hTDiay2N2qWyX4Ds7ybXi9h8I.jpg","belongs_to_collection":null,"budget":63000000,"genres":[{"id":18,"name":"Drama"}],"homepage":"http://www.foxmovies.com/movies/fight-club","id":550,"imdb_id":"tt0137523","original_language":"en","original_title":"Fight Club","overview":"A ticking-time-bomb insomniac and a slippery soap salesman channel primal male aggression into a shocking new form of therapy. Their concept catches on, with underground \"fight clubs\" forming in every town, until an eccentric gets in the way and ignites an out-of-control spiral toward oblivion.","popularity":9.884594999999999,"poster_path":"/adw6Lq9FiC9zjYEpOqfq03ituwp.jpg","production_companies":[{"name":"Regency Enterprises","id":508},{"name":"Fox 2000 Pictures","id":711},{"name":"Taurus Film","id":20555},{"name":"Linson Films","id":54050},{"name":"Atman Entertainment","id":54051},{"name":"Knickerbocker Films","id":54052}],"production_countries":[{"iso_3166_1":"DE","name":"Germany"},{"iso_3166_1":"US","name":"United States of America"}],"release_date":"1999-10-15","revenue":100853753,"runtime":139,"spoken_languages":[{"iso_639_1":"en","name":"English"}],"status":"Released","tagline":"How much can you know about yourself if you've never been in a fight?","title":"Fight Club","video":false,"vote_average":8.199999999999999,"vote_count":8036}
```

It shows fight club data, because i put fightclub IMDB ID on the url `tt0137523`

Now, If i go to this url:

```
https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/adw6Lq9FiC9zjYEpOqfq03ituwp.jpg
```

I will get Fightclub poster, because I insert `adw6Lq9FiC9zjYEpOqfq03ituwp` this key in the url, which i found from the data.

But how to use it using PHP code??

Just show me a small demo:

How to display the image in this code?

```
<?php

$posterkey = somethinghere, which gets poster key 
echo "<img src='https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/".$posterkey.".jpg
'></img";
?>
</body>
```

Edit: I also made this code, but don't know how to use it

```
<?php
$requestsDone = 0;
$maxRequests = 2;

while ($requestsDone < $maxRequests) {
        $requestsDone++;

    echo "Request number: ".$requestsDone."<br>";

    $response = file_get_contents("https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/".mt_rand(500,996)."?api_key=522xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
    $response = json_decode($response);
    print_r ($response);
    echo "<br><br><br>";
}
?>
```

Comment: This isn't a great place to ask others to write code for you. Try to write the code yourself, and ask specific questions when you run into trouble.

Comment: I will write the whole code. But just give me a small example, how to use it. I am really confused. I am trying this from 1 week, day and night. Pleasee

Comment: I have no idea, what to do next. I tried to search a lot, but nothing helped me. Just small demo, which will give me some idea @smarx

Comment: Some keywords that should help your search: you're trying to make an **HTTP request**, and then you're trying to **parse** the **JSON** in the **HTTP response**.

Comment: what are you actually asking?  how to display the image?  how to get the image key?  how to parse the json?

Comment: How to display the image? If i get the image key, i can display the image. 

I updated the question, see the new code @smarx

Comment: So you just need `$response["poster_path"]`?

Comment: You mean this? 

`$poster = $response["poster_path"];
echo "<img src='https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/".$poster."' alt=' Fight Club ' ></img>";`

But it is not working, what is wrong? @smarx

Comment: `print_r ($response["poster_path"]);` do not work

Comment: @smarx bro, last thing please

Comment: What do you mean "[does] not work"? That's not a useful description of a problem you're having.

Comment: when you post questions on SO with code that "does not work", try to include a description of what actually happens.  that way someone can help you debug the problem if they are so inclined.  so far your line of questioning is vague and impossible to answer.  most people here really want to help you but they just can't without knowing specifically what's going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code works. If yours still doesn't, try to figure out what's different.

```
$key = "<REDACTED>";

$json = file_get_contents("https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/tt0137523?api_key=$key");

$result = json_decode($json, true);

$poster_path = $result["poster_path"];

echo "<img src=\"https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500$poster_path\">";

// Output:
// <img src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/adw6Lq9FiC9zjYEpOqfq03ituwp.jpg">
```

**UPDATE**

I think the issue is that you're missing the second parameter `true` in your call to `json_decode`. Passing that will get you an associative array instead of an object, so then you can index into it as I did above.